# disabled the checkbox when there is data

Tags: vue.js

I'm studying a vue js, Im trying to disabled the checkbox when there is a data that is equal to the issue but when i'm console.logging the **issue.issue == 'Skin Allergies/Irritation'** inside the div element that has an **v-if ="issue.issue == 'Health Condition'** it will return a **false** but i have already data inside my database

```html
 <section>
     <el-collapse v-model="activeIssue" accordion>
         <el-collapse-item :title="issue.issue == 'Health Condition' ? $helper.capitalize(issue.issue) : 'Informed Consent for ' + $helper.capitalize(issue.issue)" :name="issue.id" v-for="(issue, index) in dataForm.health_issues" :key="index">
             <div v-if="!!issue.url || !issue.issue == 'Health Condition'">
                 <el-image :src="issue.url" style="width: 100%;"></el-image>
             </div>
             <div v-if ="issue.issue == 'Health Condition'" v-loading="loading">
             <div style="margin: 0 0 15px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 30px">
             <div class="-checkbox-div">
                 <el-checkbox :disabled="issue.issue == 'Skin Allergies/Irritation' " v-model="skin" class="-checkbox">Skin Allergies/Irritation </el-checkbox>
                 <span v-if="skin" class="-upload-mc">
                     <el-link type="success" :underline="false" @click="uploadCert('Skin Allergies/Irritation')">
                         Upload medical certificate
                         <i class="el-icon-circle-check el-icon--right" v-if="checkIssue('Skin Allergies/Irritation')"></i>
                     </el-link>
                 </span>
             </div>
         </el-collapse-item>
     </el-collapse>
 </section>
```

Is there a way where i can disabled the checkbox when i already have a data im trying to use this **:disabled** but inside the div that has a v-if it only returning false

Comment: Try using `===` instead of using `==` in `v-if` and `:disabled`.

Comment: I already tried it but it remain the same .  inside the div that has a v-if it only returning false
outside the <div v-if =“issue.issue == ‘Health Condition’” other issue will return true but inside the div that has a condition of health Condition it returning false , what i want is even im inside the
all the issue will still be true so i can disabled the checkbox if there a data corresponding to it

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on this line

```html
<div v-if="!!issue.url || !issue.issue == 'Health Condition'">
     <el-image :src="issue.url" style="width: 100%;"></el-image>
</div>
```

You are calling a turnery operation on `issue.issue` (`!issue.issue`) which is converting it to a boolean. Which returns [truthy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) because `"Skin Allergies/Irritation"` is [truthy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) (whereas an empty string is [falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)). Taking the opposite value of it makes it `false`.

This means that you are comparing `!true == 'Health Condition'` which becomes `false == 'Health Condition'`. Essentially you are comparing `false == true`. This in turn makes your or clause essentially `!!issue.url` as `!issue.issue == 'Health Condition'` is always false.

Therefore if you remove the `!` in your `v-if` it will actually compare the string's value

```html
<div v-if="issue.url || issue.issue == 'Health Condition'">
     <el-image :src="issue.url" style="width: 100%;"></el-image>
</div>
```

You also should remove the `!!` in front of `issue.url` as it will [already be converted](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) to a boolean when you are performing you logic